# curious to know about artificial satellites orbiting moon

Tags: artificial-satellite, the-moon, orbit

I took this pic on 16 th November 2016 two days after supermoon using a small telescope and accidentally captured some sort of satellite pic along with the moon.i am curious to know howmany such satellites are currently orbiting moon.[image]

Comment: Nothing orbiting the moon would be that large by comparison. *Assuming* that is in fact a satellite, it would have to be a lot closer than the moon. [Here](http://www.space.com/29889-space-station-crosses-moon-photo.html) is what it looks like when the International Space Station transits the moon.

Comment: Adding to what @called2voyage wrote, anything with a track that straight would have to be a significant distance from the moon *or* would be in a very, very weird orbit. What was the exposure time for that picture? I wouldn't be surprised if it's an aircraft or something like that...

Comment: It was around 8:50 pm in delhi ncr , india when I took this pic.

Comment: Sorry. "Exposure time" isn't *the time at which the picture was taken* but rather *for what amount of time the picture was being exposed*. In other words: was the camera shutter open for 1/100 of a second, half a second, a second, or what?

Comment: But I took many other shots continually and only this one captured this satellite kind of image.so I want to be sure of exactly what is this.

Comment: What kind of camera did you take this with? Also, see http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/exif-photo-data-find-understand/ for how to get the EXIF data, you might just post all of it, it could be helpful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For any camera, the Moon is approximately 0.5 degrees across.

Measuring the photo on my monitor, I find the Moon is 10.5 cm across, while the "satellite" is 3.0 cm from top to bottom.  So by simple ratio, the "satellite" is 0.143 degrees across. This converts to a much more useful 0.0025 radians.

So, if the "satellite" was at lunar distance, its length would be:$$Length_{lunar}=0.0025*384000=960 \text{ km}$$If the "satellite" is in geosynchronous earth orbit, its length would be:$$L_{GEO}=0.0025*36000=90 \text{ km}$$If the "satellite" is in low earth orbit, its length would be:$$L_{LEO}=0.0025*400=1 \text{ km}$$If the "satellite" is a plane at around $10,000$ feet, its length (wingspan) would be:$$L_{Plane}=0.0025*3000=7.5 \text{ m}$$

Which of these seem even remotely possible?

Comment: Might add too that at a more reasonable airliner cruise altitude of 10 km, the corresponding wingspan would be 25 meters, whereas Wikipedia gives the wingspan of for example the Boeing 767 as a little under 48 meters. Not sure if the 48 meters is length or width tip-to-tip, but especially if it's length, it's definitely in the right ballpark.

Comment: I assumed it was a moving streak, with the size not really being all that critical to the size that appeared, but still, interesting thought.

Answer (score 7):

Unless you had a VERY powerful telescope, you didn't capture an image of a satellite orbiting the moon. From [Which artificial satellites in lunar orbit are currently active?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/221/25) we have 3 spacecraft that are known to be orbiting the Moon, and the largest of these is LRO. The solar panels are the largest part, at [10.7 m^2 area](http://pds-geosciences.wustl.edu/missions/lro/docs/lro_insthost.txt). It's too small to even be seen by Hubble, which can only see an object the distance of the moon about 200m in one dimension!

Furthermore, the orbiting period of a satellite would be about 113 minutes, as LRO's period is. The orbital of the object would be about 1/16th of an orbit, so you would have had to have an exposure of about 7 minutes to capture that!

More likely you are either seeing an aircraft, or possibly a satellite orbiting the Earth.

Comment: Thanks for such an explanation giving so much of information regarding  LRO.

Comment: The two ARTEMIS probes (formerly known as THEMIS-B and THEMIS-C) have been in lunar orbit since 2010 and are still operating more-or-less nominally, collecting field and particle data.  http://artemis.ssl.berkeley.edu/summary.php?year=2016&month=11&day=30&hour=0024&sumType=thb&type=overview

Comment: Fair point, I hadn't heard actually they orbited the Moon. The same principal applies.

Answer (score 3):

This is what a satellite in orbit around the moon *actually looks like in an actual photograph*. After careful calculations and preparation, LRO was able to photograph LADEE while both of them were orbiting the Moon.

The spacecraft were separated by only 9 kilometers. By comparison, on the evening of your photograph the moon was about 361,000 kilometers from the Earth.

[image]

**above:** Photograph of LADEE taken by LRO, both in orbit around the moon, from [here](https://lpod.wikispaces.com/January+30%2C+2014), seemingly cropped, from [here](http://lroc.sese.asu.edu/posts/736).